# LALR(2) dangling else

Tags: parsing, compiler-theory, lalr

Is LALR(2) able to handle the dangling else case naturally (without any special rules, as with LALR(1))?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's ambiguous, however, it's not a problem, because a well behaved LALR parser generator will resolve the ambiguity by choosing the shift instead of the reduce choice.  This is what you want -- the "else" to be matched with the previous "if" statement.  So the conclusion is: there is no problem.  You just have to understand the default choice which the parser generator makes for all shift-reduce ambiguities.  This default can be overridden with disambiguating rules or something like the "%prec" operator in "yacc".
But that is a more advanced topic.

Comment: Great information! I've accepted your answer instead, for being more elaborate.

Answer (score 5):

No, the dangling else problem is an ambiguity, so no amount of lookahead helps.